# "I got error in node.js to connect mongo db"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
db connection error querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.nodeapi.vlvom.mongodb.net
(node:7720) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.nodeapi.vlvom.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:203:19)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:7720) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7720) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
GET / 200 66.595 ms - 58
```

**Why I got above error in node.js? Can anyone help me?**

Comment: It looks like you're running into an `ENOTFOUND` error, indicating that Mongoose can't find the database you're trying to connect to. Verify that your connection string is correct. Also, it would help if you included the code in your question where you connect to the database so we can see what's causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve my problem. The solution to my error is I used node.js oldest version and then I used the latest version to solve this.